# Help: Shifted columns values of a dataset

Tags: dataset, python, column

How do i add a new column to a `Dataset` that is the shifted version of another column with nulls placed in missing places. (just like the function shift in pandas in python)

```
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html
```

Also is there any source where i can learn about all the behaviors of `Dataset`. Is there any book or tutorials about `Dataset`?

Comment: Define "shifted version" and provide some code that demonstrates the issue and the output you expect.

Comment: The example provided by mdc18550 is what i am after.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20095673/python-shift-column-in-pandas-dataframe-up-by-one but using mathematica's `Dataset`

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that what you want to do is similar to the following example:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20095673/python-shift-column-in-pandas-dataframe-up-by-one

One way to do this it to round trip from the dataset to a matrix and back to a dataset using Normal. To replicate the data from the above stackoverflow example:

```
data={{1, 2, 5}, {2, 3, 9}, {8, 7, 2}, {3, 4, 7}, {6, 7, 7}};
ds = Dataset[AssociationThread[{"y", "gdp", "cap"} -> #] & /@ data];
```

[image]

You can extract the data from the dataset and then use ReplacePart to perform the lag and "null". I assume here that null==0 since it isn't clear from the question. As per the example above, I also assume the second column is the one being lagged.

```
colVals = Transpose@ds // Normal // Values;
lagCol = 2;
inpL = Transpose@
  ReplacePart[colVals, lagCol -> Join[Rest[colVals[[lagCol]]], {0}]]
ds2 = Dataset[AssociationThread[{"y", "gdp", "cap"} -> #] & /@ inpL]
```

The result is:

[image]

In response to user13892's further comment. The underlying structure of Dataset objects are lists of associations in which the row is defined by the Association and the columns are inferred from keys common to the Associations. While data can be easily extracted by rows or columns, it is more difficult to modify columns without resorting to the underlying structures.

Perhaps you will find this solution more to your liking, although it still relys on running the data through Normal.

```
shift[l_List] := Join[Drop[RotateLeft[l], -1], {0}]
ds1 = ds // Normal;
ds2=Dataset[MapThread[Append, {ds1, ("gdp" -> # & /@ Query[shift, "gdp"]@ds1)}]]
```

Comment: I wanted a solution where you don't have to do back to the primary mathematica data structures `List` but use `Dataset` with some `Query` option or others to solve the problem.